# Get last modified object from S3 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a use case where I programmatically bring up an EC2 instance, copy an executable file from S3, run it and shut down the instance (done in user-data). I need to get only the last added file from S3.

Is there a way to get the last modified file / object from a S3 bucket using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool?

Comment: can you involve a programming language at all

Comment: CLI will be the best option since I plan to have it in the user-data during instance launch.

Comment: Do you program in any languages with s3?

Comment: Is there a better solution for buckets with 2M+ objects?

Comment: For a lot of objects, I think a better solution would be to create an `Event/Lambda` on the object that gets triggered on `ObjectCreation`. fetching the last object among 2M+ objects using s3 cli or api is way to slower.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can list all the objects in the bucket with `aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive`:

```
$ aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive
2015-05-05 15:36:17          4 an_object.txt
2015-06-08 14:14:44   16322599 some/other/object
2015-04-29 12:09:29      32768 yet-another-object.sh
```

They're sorted alphabetically by key, but that first column is the last modified time. A quick `sort` will reorder them by date:

```
$ aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort
2015-04-29 12:09:29      32768 yet-another-object.sh
2015-05-05 15:36:17          4 an_object.txt
2015-06-08 14:14:44   16322599 some/other/object
```

`tail -n 1` selects the last row, and `awk '{print $4}'` extracts the fourth column (the name of the object).

```
$ aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
some/other/object
```

Last but not least, drop that into `aws s3 cp` to download the object:

```
$ KEY=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
$ aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$KEY ./latest-object
```

Comment: Brilliant post. Particularly useful due to the explanations of each command. Thanks.

Comment: S3 only indexes objects by key. If the bucket has enough objects that a "full table scan" to find the one you're looking for is impractical, you'll need to build a separate index of your own. The laziest option I can think of is to put the key of the most recently written object in s3://$BUCKET/current after you've written it, and have readers look there to find which one they should pull.

Comment: Just a side note, if you want to the same thing for a whole "folder", `awk` will need to select the second element (instead of 4th) and `--recursive` will be needed, e.g., `KEY=\`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'\` ; aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$KEY ./latest-object --recursive`

Comment: This won't work on buckets with more than 1000 items, because that is the most that can be returned https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

Comment: isn't this going to pose problems on a bucket with a HUGE number of objects?

Comment: is there a windows batch file version of this available?

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation. I am getting confused in the last part where the cp command is used. What is the key in the command & where to get it from?

Answer (score 74):

## Updated answer

After a while there is a small update how to do it a bit elegant:

```sh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "my-awesome-bucket" --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output=text
```

Instead of extra `reverse` function we can get last entry from the list via `[-1]`

---

### Old answer

This command just do the job without any external dependencies:

```sh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "my-awesome-bucket" --query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents, &LastModified))[:1].Key' --output=text
```

Comment: Excellent. If you also need the object name to match a certain string: `--query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents[?contains(Key, \`myKey\`)], &LastModified))[:1].Key'`

Comment: --query is executed locally, so if you have more than 1000 files in the bucket you are not guaranteed to get the last modified ones first.

Comment: @GismoRanas Good point. The regular `--filter` option can be applied to reduce a list

Comment: This one works in Windows cmd if you wrap the query in double quotes rather than single.

Comment: For large buckets it is recommended to use a hierarchical key naming scheme so you can take advantage of the `--prefix` option in order to reduce the searched key list.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 11):

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "bucket-name" |jq  -c ".[] | max_by(.LastModified)|.Key"
```

Comment: If you've never met jq before, it's a json processor https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I think `list-objects-v2` has a limit on max items, so if your bucket has more objects than that - this might not get an accurate answer

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html  states (as of this writing) that the maximum limit _per page_ is 1000. Also note that the output has `IsTruncated` set to true if more keys are available to return.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a freshly uploaded file, you can use [Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html) to execute a piece of code on the new S3 object.

If you really need to get the most recent one, you can name you files with the date first, sort by name, and take the first object.

Comment: This is unfortunately not a freshly uploaded file. I will need the last uploaded file which could have been uploaded at anytime.

Answer (score -2):

Following is bash script, that downloads latest file from a S3 Bucket. I used AWS S3 **Synch** command instead, so that it would not download the file from S3 if already existing.

--exclude, excludes all the files

--include, includes all the files matching the pattern

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    BUCKET="s3://my-s3-bucket-eu-west-1/list/"
    FILE_NAME=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET  | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`
    TARGET_FILE_PATH=target/datdump/
    TARGET_FILE=${TARGET_FILE_PATH}localData.json.gz

    echo $FILE_NAME
    echo $TARGET_FILE

    aws s3 sync $BUCKET $TARGET_FILE_PATH --exclude "*" --include "*$FILE_NAME*"

    cp target/datdump/$FILE_NAME $TARGET_FILE
```

p.s. Thanks @David Murray

Comment: Very inefficient.  My folder is 29T large.  Sorting should be done on the server side, not by downloading all of the files and piping into sort.