# Downloading the latest file in an S3 bucket using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an S3 bucket that contains database backups. I am creating a script to download the latest backup (and eventually restore it somewhere else), but I'm not sure how to go about only grabbing the **most recent** file from a bucket.

Is it possible to copy only the most recent file from an S3 bucket to a local directory using AWS CLI tools?

Comment: What are you gonna use for scripting? SDK, CLI or something else? Also how are you naming the back files in S3

Comment: What do you mean by most recent? dont the files have different names?

Comment: Are you using s3 file versioning?

Comment: @error2007s I'm using CLI.  The files are named in a few different formats, but it typically contains a name and date component.  I could potentially work on something to parse the dates but I would prefer not to if I can avoid it

Comment: @Shibashis I mean the file that was most recently created.  Yes - the files have different names.  I am not using versioning.

Comment: The accepted answer is a copy-and-paste duplicate of the accepted answer of the earlier question. See my comment below the accepted answer here.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Were you able to setup automated download and restore process ?
If yes, Can you please share the scripts you used. ?

I would like to setup a automated job to download and restore from the latest backup file.

Answer (score 27):

And here is a bash script create based on @error2007s's answer.  This script requires your aws profile and bucket name as variables, and downloads the latest object to your ~/Downloads folder:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROFILE=your_profile
BUCKET=your_bucket

OBJECT="$(aws s3 ls --profile $PROFILE $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')"
aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$OBJECT ~/Downloads/$OBJECT --profile $PROFILE
```

Comment: Worth noting that AWS now has Cloud Console so you can do this directly from the AWS Console.

Comment: This might be more helpful by getting the more recent files (specify your date) from your bucket, then copy only those...using sort and tail perhaps to get the latest and list it (which could then be used for copying): 
```aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --query 'Contents[?LastModified>`2023-02-09`].{ Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified }' --output text | sort -k2 | tail -1```
  [stack**overflow** Hat tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433079/11972755). Hope this helps.

Comment: A better CLI method to get latest key per [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451831/11972755) is: ```aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $BUCKET --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output=text```

Answer (score 9):

```
FILE=`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "$BUCKET_NAME" --query 'reverse(sort_by(Contents[?contains(Key, \`$FILE_NAME_FILTER\`)], &LastModified))[:1].Key' --output=text`;aws s3 cp "s3://$BUCKET_NAME/$FILE" .
```

**$BUCKET_NAME** - is the bucket from which you want to download.

**$FILE_NAME_FILTER** - a string used as a filter for the name, which you want to match.

**aws s3 cp " "** - its in double-quotes because to also include files that have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 8):

The above solutions are using Bash. If one wants to do the same thing in **PowerShell** for downloading on Windows here is the script:

```
# This assumes AWS CLI exe is in your path.
$s3location = "s3://bucket-name"
$files = $(aws s3 ls $s3location --recursive | sort | select -last 3)
$dlPath = "C:\TEMP"

foreach ($s3FileInfo in $files) {
    $filename = $s3FileInfo.Split()[-1]
    $path = "${s3location}/${filename}"
    aws s3 cp $path $dlPath
    echo("Done downloading ${path} to ${dlPath}")
}
```