# How list Amazon S3 bucket contents by modified date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Most of the time it happens that we load files in a common S3 bucket due to which it becomes hard to figure out data in it.

How can I view objects uploaded on a particular date?

Answer (score 89):

One solution would probably to use the [`s3api`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/index.html). It works easily if you have less than 1000 objects, otherwise you need to work with pagination.

`s3api` can list all objects and has a property for the `lastmodified` attribute of keys imported in s3. It can then be sorted, find files after or before a date, matching a date ...

Examples of running such option

1. all files for a given date

```sh
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
bucket=test-bucket-fh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "$bucket" \
    --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `'"$DATE"'`)]'
```

2. all files after a certain date

```sh
SINCE=`date --date '-2 weeks +2 days' +%F 2>/dev/null || date -v '-2w' -v '+2d' +%F`
#      ^^^^ GNU style                                    ^^^^ BSD style
bucket=test-bucket-fh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "$bucket" \
    --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `'"$SINCE"'`]'
```

s3api will return a [few metadata](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html#output) so you can filter for specific elements

```sh
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
bucket=test-bucket-fh
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "$bucket" \
    --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `'"$DATE"'`)].Key'
```

Comment: This should be a chosen answer. The other answers suggest `ls`  the objects in the bucket then sorting, which will be expensive.

Comment: This is very promising but when I run the export command in bash I get the error message date: invalid option -- 'v'

Comment: @Tim This would depend of the `date` program you have, you can check `man date` for the correct flag available, you can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706882/get-the-date-a-day-before-current-time-in-bash for the different flavour of date

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri . I have "date (GNU coreutils) 8.22". I found another way around this, which I'll post as an answer.

Comment: aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "bucketname" --query 'Contents[?LastModified > `2019-07-20`]

Comment: @NicholasPorter awscli's `--query` option is implemented on the client side, no? I fail to see how this approach would be any cheaper than the other approaches suggested.

Comment: Also, according to the [JMES docs](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#filterexpressions): "Ordering operators >, >=, <, <= are only valid for numbers. Evaluating any other type with a comparison operator will yield a null value, which will result in the element being excluded from the result list." `LastModified` is a string, so `>` doesn't work on it.

Comment: Did you even try this solution? Your query expression is completely invalid: `Bad value for --query Contents[?LastModified > ]: invalid token: Parse error at column 25, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:`

Comment: @Cerin yes It was tried and I believe 70+ users acknowledges it is working. your query `Contents[?LastModified > ]` does not contain anything to compare so yes it comes as an error, you can use plain text value to test `Contents[?LastModified >` `2022-01-01` `]`

Comment: THIS IS A CLIENT SIDE FILTER, DO NOT DO THIS EXPECTING IT TO WORK.

Answer (score 37):

Search on a given date

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET_NAME --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `YYYY-MM-DD`)].Key'
```

Search from a certain date to today

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET_NAME  --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`YYYY-MM-DD`].Key'
```

You can optionally remove the `.Key` from the end of the query to grab all metadata fields from the s3 objects

Comment: This is the best answer. It's simple and it works

Comment: Note if you want to query a specific 'folder' in the bucket, you use the `--prefix` option.  Eg. `--prefix "folder/subfolder`"

Comment: you saved my day buddy 

Comment: I really wish people would stop posting this same incorrect answer. Why would you even put backticks around the date? You're trying to execute the date? That's clearly invalid syntax.

Comment: @Cerin It actually is valid syntax; the backticks are in a string that's surrounded by single quotes, so they're treated as literal backticks as far as the shell is concerned. To the AWS CLI, the backticks are used to identify strings in a query clause ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html)).

Comment: THIS IS A CLIENT SIDE FILTER, DO NOT DO THIS EXPECTING IT TO WORK.

Answer (score 13):

In case it helps anyone in the future, here's a python program that will allow you to filter by a set of prefixes, suffixes, and/or last modified date. Note that you'll need aws credentials set up properly in order to use boto3. **Note that this supports prefixes that contain more than 1000 keys.**

Usage:

```
python save_keys_to_file.py -b 'bucket_name' -p some/prefix -s '.txt' '.TXT' -f '/Path/To/Some/File/test_keys.txt' -n '2018-1-1' -x '2018-2-1'
```

Code filename: **save_keys_to_file.py**:

```py
    import argparse
    import boto3
    import dateutil.parser
    import logging
    import pytz
    from collections import namedtuple

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


    Rule = namedtuple('Rule', ['has_min', 'has_max'])
    last_modified_rules = {
        Rule(has_min=True, has_max=True):
            lambda min_date, date, max_date: min_date <= date <= max_date,
        Rule(has_min=True, has_max=False):
            lambda min_date, date, max_date: min_date <= date,
        Rule(has_min=False, has_max=True):
            lambda min_date, date, max_date: date <= max_date,
        Rule(has_min=False, has_max=False):
            lambda min_date, date, max_date: True,
    }


    def get_s3_objects(bucket, prefixes=None, suffixes=None, last_modified_min=None, last_modified_max=None):
        """
        Generate the objects in an S3 bucket. Adapted from:
        https://alexwlchan.net/2017/07/listing-s3-keys/

        :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
        :ptype bucket: str
        :param prefixes: Only fetch keys that start with these prefixes (optional).
        :ptype prefixes: tuple
        :param suffixes: Only fetch keys that end with thes suffixes (optional).
        :ptype suffixes: tuple
        :param last_modified_min: Only yield objects with LastModified dates greater than this value (optional).
        :ptype last_modified_min: datetime.date
        :param last_modified_max: Only yield objects with LastModified dates greater than this value (optional).
        :ptype last_modified_max: datetime.date

        :returns: generator of dictionary objects
        :rtype: dict https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects
        """
        if last_modified_min and last_modified_max and last_modified_max < last_modified_min:
            raise ValueError(
                "When using both, last_modified_max: {} must be greater than last_modified_min: {}".format(
                    last_modified_max, last_modified_min
                )
            )
        # Use the last_modified_rules dict to lookup which conditional logic to apply
        # based on which arguments were supplied
        last_modified_rule = last_modified_rules[bool(last_modified_min), bool(last_modified_max)]

        if not prefixes:
            prefixes = ('',)
        else:
            prefixes = tuple(set(prefixes))
        if not suffixes:
            suffixes = ('',)
        else:
            suffixes = tuple(set(suffixes))

        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket}

        for prefix in prefixes:
            kwargs['Prefix'] = prefix
            while True:
                # The S3 API response is a large blob of metadata.
                # 'Contents' contains information about the listed objects.
                resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
                for content in resp.get('Contents', []):
                    last_modified_date = content['LastModified']
                    if (
                        content['Key'].endswith(suffixes) and
                        last_modified_rule(last_modified_min, last_modified_date, last_modified_max)
                    ):
                        yield content

                # The S3 API is paginated, returning up to 1000 keys at a time.
                # Pass the continuation token into the next response, until we
                # reach the final page (when this field is missing).
                try:
                    kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
                except KeyError:
                    break


    def get_s3_keys(bucket, prefixes=None, suffixes=None, last_modified_min=None, last_modified_max=None):
        """
        Generate the keys in an S3 bucket.

        :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
        :ptype bucket: str
        :param prefixes: Only fetch keys that start with these prefixes (optional).
        :ptype prefixes: tuple
        :param suffixes: Only fetch keys that end with thes suffixes (optional).
        :ptype suffixes: tuple
        :param last_modified_min: Only yield objects with LastModified dates greater than this value (optional).
        :ptype last_modified_min: datetime.date
        :param last_modified_max: Only yield objects with LastModified dates greater than this value (optional).
        :ptype last_modified_max: datetime.date
        """
        for obj in get_s3_objects(bucket, prefixes, suffixes, last_modified_min, last_modified_max):
            yield obj['Key']


    def valid_datetime(date):
        if date is None:
            return date
        try:
            utc = pytz.UTC
            return utc.localize(dateutil.parser.parse(date))
        except Exception:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Could not parse value: '{}' to type datetime".format(date))


    def main():
        FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='List keys in S3 bucket for prefix')
        parser.add_argument('-b', '--bucket', help='S3 Bucket')
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--prefixes', nargs='+', help='Filter s3 keys by a set of prefixes')
        parser.add_argument('-s', '--suffixes', nargs='*', help='Filter s3 keys by a set of suffixes')
        parser.add_argument('-n', '--last_modified_min', default=None, type=valid_datetime, help='Filter s3 content by minimum last modified date')
        parser.add_argument('-x', '--last_modified_max', default=None, type=valid_datetime, help='Filter s3 content by maximum last modified date')
        parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='Optional: file to write keys to.', default=None)

        args = parser.parse_args()
        logger.info(args)
        keys = get_s3_keys(args.bucket, args.prefixes, args.suffixes, args.last_modified_min, args.last_modified_max)

        open_file = open(args.file, 'w') if args.file else None
        try:
            counter = 0
            for key in keys:
                print(key, file=open_file)
                counter += 1
        finally:
            open_file.close()

        logger.info('Retrieved {} keys'.format(counter))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 11):

BTW this works on Windows if you want to search between dates

`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --max-items 10 --bucket "BUCKET" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2019-10-01 00:00:00'] | [?LastModified<='2019-10-30 00:00:00'].{ Key: Key, Size: Size, LastModified: LastModified }"`

Comment: Using this method, I had to add the `--prefix` flag to get into nested directories. Question: How do I remove the prefix from the key? I want only the file name alone instead of `"Key": "parent-dir1/parent-dir2/file_name"`.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a general solution, but can be helpful where your objects are named based on date - such as CloudTrail logs. For example, I wanted a list of objects created in June 2019.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucketname --prefix path/2019-06
```

This does the filtering on the server side. The downside of using the "query" parameter is it downloads a lot of data to filter on the client side. This means potentially a lot of API calls, which cost money, and additional data egress from AWS that you pay for.

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2543

Answer (score 9):

The following command works in Linux.

```
aws s3 ls --recursive s3:// <your s3 path here> | awk '$1 > "2018-10-13 00:00:00" {print $0}' | sort -n
```

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: Beware this approach will be expensive if you have a lot of objects in the bucket. You still get charged for listing objects. Check out @frédéric-henri answer below.

Answer (score 9):

If you have massive amounts of files (millions or billions of entries), the best way to go is to generate a bucket inventory using **Amazon S3 Inventory**, including the Last Modified field, and then query the generated inventory via **Amazon Athena** using SQL queries.

You can find a detailed walkthrough here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/manage-and-analyze-your-data-at-scale-using-amazon-s3-inventory-and-amazon-athena/

Comment: Finally an answer that actually works at scale, while it might not be the best to handle fully managed, it is 100x better than the other "solutions" to this question. Please listen to Guillermo.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there is no API that lets you filter by modified date on the server-side. All the filtering seems to be happening on the client-side, so no matter what client you use (s3api, boto3, etc) it will be slow if you have to do that on a large number of files. There is no good option to parallelize that scan unless you can do that by running a list operation on different subfolders, but that's definitely not going to work for a lot of cases.

The only option I've found that actually gives you the ability to filter a large number of files by modified date is to use AWS S3 inventory - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html. This way AWS runs the S3 files indexing for you and stores the files' metadata (i.e. file path, last modified date, size, etc) in a specified S3 location. You can easily use that to filter by modified date.

Answer (score 1):

If versioning is enabled for the bucket and you want to restore latest deleted objects after a specific date, this is the command:

```
$ aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket --prefix myprefix/ --output json --query 'DeleteMarkers[?LastModified>=`2020-07-07T00:00:00` && IsLatest==`true`].[Key,VersionId]' | jq -r '.[] |  "--key '\''" + .[0] +  "'\'' --version-id " + .[1]' |xargs -L1 aws s3api delete-object --bucket mybucket
```

That means that you have `aws cli` (I used v. 2.0.30) and `jq` installed.

---

If you want to be sure before deleting that everything is ok, just use `echo` before `aws`:

```
$ aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket --prefix myprefix/ --output json --query 'DeleteMarkers[?LastModified>=`2020-07-07T00:00:00` && IsLatest==`true`].[Key,VersionId]' | jq -r '.[] |  "--key '\''" + .[0] +  "'\'' --version-id " + .[1]' |xargs -L1 echo aws s3api delete-object --bucket mybucket > files.txt
```

Note that because of `echo`, quotes will be not applied correctly and saved in the file without it. That's ok if there are no spaces in paths.
You can check that file and if everything is ok, run in this way:

```
$ cat files.txt | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

If versioning is enabled for the bucket and you want to list last modified objects after a specific date, this is the command:

```
$ aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "bucket_name" --prefix "prefix" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2023-01-23'].{key: Key, date: LastModified}"
```