# aws ruby sdk - read a pretty large file from S3

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to read around 1.5GB size from s3 using ruby sdk for aws.
S3 gem is - gem 'aws-sdk' ( https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby )

```
most_recent_s3_object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects.max_by(&:last_modified)
```

Here most_recent_s3_object class is Aws::S3::ObjectSummary
When I do `most_recent_s3_object.get` I get broken pipe error.
Is there a way around to get this file in a whole for this size?

Comment: Which S3 gem are you using? What is the `class` of `most_recent_s3_object`?

Comment: @JaredBeck updated the question with these details.

Comment: `objects.max_by(&:last_modified)` is downloading every object from the entire bucket in order to find the most recently modified one. Unfortunately this kind of thing is unavailable server side for s3. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1104 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429556/how-list-amazon-s3-bucket-contents-by-modified-date

Comment: You can use `s3api list-objects` but it's still client side filtering and only works up to a limited # of objects