# How do I query AWS S3 bucket for N last modified objects using the REST API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the Rest API (not CLI), How do I query an AWS S3 bucket for N last modified objects?

Comment: Which language you are looking for ?

Comment: any, curl / postman. just looking for the request spec

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429556/how-list-amazon-s3-bucket-contents-by-modified-date

Comment: There is no such API, you'll need to use ListObjects to list all of the objects and filter based off your criteria locally.