refactor to limit to use lastModified<=15
Yes, we can use the aws s3api... to filter the keys that is older than 15 days by means of running below command (below returns expected result):
lastModifiedMax=`date -d "15 days ago" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
aws s3api list-objects --bucket $bucket  --query "Contents[?LastModified<='${lastModifiedMax}'][].{object: Key}"

However, we want to use in python boto3, using this sample piece of the script - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877685/27921578
Which is, we tried to replace this below lines
  while True:
                # The S3 API response is a large blob of metadata.
                # 'Contents' contains information about the listed objects.
                resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
                for content in resp.get('Contents', []):
                    last_modified_date = content['LastModified']
                    if (
                        content['Key'].endswith(suffixes) and
                        last_modified_rule(last_modified_min, last_modified_date, last_modified_max)
                    ):
                        yield content


With :
    end_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=15)

    for prefix in prefixes:
        kwargs['Prefix'] = prefix
        while True:
            # The S3 API response is a large blob of metadata.
            # 'Contents' contains information about the listed objects.
            resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
            for content in resp.get('Contents', ['?LastModified<='+str(end_date)]):
                    yield content

The above changes did not give expected result, means, returned "whole" keys (whole timetamp).
Please advise what is wrong.

never mind - debugged/researched, we can achieve by means of this
           for content in resp.get('Contents',  []):
                if (
                        content['Key'] and content['LastModified'] <= datetime.now().astimezone() - timedelta(days=15)
                    ):
                    yield content


