# Copy file from the s3 to the local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, boto

I have a lot of files in my s3 bucket, so is there any aws cli command which I can use to find a most recent file with a prefix name in s3? and how can I copy that file from s3 to my local folder? Can I use Boto3 or python library to do this?

Comment: Usually you would arrange your data in a format that makes this easier. You can put files in `YEAR/MONTH/DAY/file` path for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's show to do it in Python:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='MY-BUCKET', Prefix='foo/')
objects = sorted(response['Contents'], key=lambda obj: obj['LastModified'])

## Latest object
latest_object = objects[-1]['Key']
filename = latest_object[latest_object.rfind('/')+1:] # Remove path

# Download it to current directory
s3_client.download_file('MY-BUCKET', latest_object, filename)
```

Basically, you get back ALL objects, then sort them by `LastModified`.

Please note that the `list_objects_v2()` command only returns a maximum of 1000 objects. If the bucket has more, you'll need to loop or use a paginator. See: [Paginators — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html)

Answer (score 4):

This command will list the 'latest' object for a given prefix:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --prefix foo/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

You could combine it with a copy command:

```
key=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --prefix foo/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text)
aws s3 cp s3://MY-BUCKET/$key .
```

The `--query` parameter is *very* powerful. See: [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

Comment: How can I use this in the Python Script?

Comment: I'll add another answer for Python. (Sorry, your question was confusing because you mentioned both AWS CLI and boto.)

Comment: Upvoted this one because I didn't realise the `--query` option. Thanks!!! This solves a different problem whilst I was here

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this answer for most recent file. [get last modified object from S3 CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062365/get-last-modified-object-from-s3-cli/31064378#31064378). For prefix to be in the object list you can just use

```
aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | grep <prefix>
```

Thanks

Ashish