# Shell script - How to copy the last modified AWS S3 Object from one bucket to another?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, scripting

I'm new to scripting and writing a Shell script to copy AWS S3 object from one AWS account bucket to another bucket? A pipeline uploads zip files (.zip) to a bucket. The shell script should *only copy* the last modified object(file). I know that in shell script, you can recursively find files  based on wildcard matching and get last uploaded object from S3 CLI. Is there a more elegant and effective way of doing it?

```
# Normal way of copying from one bucket to another
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/object-v2.2.7.zip s3://destination- bucket/.

# Using the --recursive parameter to copy file
aws s3 ls $source-bucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'

  
get_object = `aws s3 ls $source-bucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`

aws s3 cp s3://$get_object s3://destination-bucket
echo 'Successfully uploaded file to Destination Bucket'
```

Comment: be aware that listing all objects in a large bucket is a slow and expensive operation, and that s3 is not guaranteed to be read after write consistent.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Good to know, do you have any suggestions on how to do this operation more elegantly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script finds the last modified object and then copies it.

```sh
SOURCE_BUCKET=bucket1
DEST_BUCKET=bucket2

LAST=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text)

aws s3 cp s3://$SOURCE_BUCKET/$LAST s3://$DEST_BUCKET
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062365/get-last-modified-object-from-s3-cli) to get last modified objects in S3.

Once you get the object, you can put a [loop](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-for-loop/) and inside the loop you can call [`aws s3 cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command to copy files. Please let me if it works for you.